# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined error javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function onChatHandler(target, context, msg, self) {
if (self) { return; }

const xxs = ["asd","asdw"];
const commandName = msg.trim();
if (xxs.some(word => msg.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
  const num = rollDice();
  client.say(target, `Gelen sayi ${num}`);
  console.log(`* Bu ${commandName} komut kullanildi.`);
 
}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined error

Comment: Can you provide more information about msg? What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: `msg` uses `trim`, but that's for a string. So, naturally `.content` would be undefined.

Comment: I want to trigger with more than one command.

Comment: *"I want to trigger with more than one command."* - could you clarify what do you mean by that? Trigger *what* exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.toLowerCase` is for a string. Value prototypes don't work on an `undefined` value (e.g: `undefined.forEach` or `undefined.keys`), nor do they work for values that don't belong to that prototype of that value (e.g: `"string".push`).

This error means that you are calling `.toLowerCase` on a value that is undefined, so, using logic we can conclude that `msg.content` is undefined.

To fix it, I recommend some debugging (try to `console.log` msg if you can, and see what it contains).